# JQuery - Go through every instance of div with class and add class to the first n items

Tags: jquery

I have some boxes

```
<div class='ICS_Picture'>
Text
</div>
<div class='ICS_Picture'>
Text
</div>
<div class='ICS_Picture'>
Text
</div>
<div class='ICS_Picture'>
Text
</div>
```

I want jquery to add a class to all items after the first n number of items..

I have some similar code that does it for tr's but cannot get the syntax right for the current item.

```
$('.ICS_Picture').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("hideme");
});
```

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('.ICS_Picture:lt(n)').addClass('hideme');
```

With n being the number of elements to which you wish to apply the class.  So if you want to apply it to the first four elements, n = 4.

EDIT--

I just reread the question and OP is looking to apply the styles to items AFTER a certain number.  In that case, please use this instead:

```
$('.ICS_Picture:gt(n-1').addClass('hideme');
```

Please note the n-1 because the indexing is zero-based and so if you want to start applying the styles after the 4th element you'll need to ensure that the value you provide is 3.  Obviously, standard concatenation rules will apply if you plan for n to be a dynamic value rather than hard-coded.

Comment: just to clarify $('.ICS_Picture:lt(' + n + ')').addClass('hideme');

Comment: Hum, I thought that he wanted to apply the class to all but the N first items ?

Comment: or `$('.ICS_Picture:gt(n)').addClass('hideme');` for items after a certain number.

Comment: I think this si the most elegant response so far, but he needs the :gt version.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.ICS_Picture:gt(4)').addClass('hideeme');
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, each is not the most optimized way to iterate through a jquery object.

What you can do to achieve what you want is:

```
    var $ICSPictures = $('.ICS_Picture');
    for (var i=0;i<$ICSPictures.length;i++){
      if(i>=myLimit)
        $ICSPictures.eq(i).addClass("hideme");
    }
```

`myLimit` being the number *n* you're refering to in your question.

Comment: Please justify the downvote. this solution works, even though Sunny Boy's one is better.

Comment: funny how you "optimize" the callback, but don't mind querying the dom over and over.  -1

Comment: No -1 from me, but "just somebody" is correct.  For each iteration you're hitting the DOM to find the correct element.  Better to get them all at once (outside your loop) and then loop through them.

Comment: minor recommendation: `for (var i=0, j=$ICSPictures.length; i < j; i++)` P.S., ... what's so bad about `each`?

Comment: You should check out that Google Talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with the [gt() selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt#index) :

```
var toSkip = 4;
$('.ICS_Picture:gt(' + (toSkip - 1) + ')').addClass("hideme");
```

Comment: -1: `$('.ICS_Picture').each(function (count) ...` if you insist on `each`, but it's unnecessary anyway

Comment: Yep, I was just referring to his code, but I'll just remove it and keep the gt version.